# Why do I get very low fps even at minimum settings for far cry 4?

Tags: far-cry-4, windows-10, framerate, boot-camp

Im using MacBook Pro 2012 non retina base model running Windows 10.

[image]

As per steam the minimum requirements are given as
[image]

My question is why its not even playable in 800x600(minimum) resolution in comfortable frame rate? how can I improve it?

Comment: Well for one, you're not on one of the recommended operating systems. Based off your processor speed, that is below the minimum processor recommended.  But I think the real problem is your graphics.  Just look at the specs for a [GTX 460](http://graphics-cards.specout.com/l/31/Nvidia-GeForce-GTX-460) compared to your [Intel Specs](http://graphics-cards.specout.com/l/2459/Intel-HD-Graphics-4000)

Comment: @TimmyJim is right, you don't even almost meet the standard minimum requirements. You don't have a Windows operating system, you don't have the speed required for the processor, and I don't believe the onboard Intel graphics are enough.

Comment: how do I resolve it as graphics hardware is integrated

Comment: Since its a laptop, you can't.  You need a desktop, and then you need to put a real graphics card into it. I also see you tagged boot-camp and Windows 10.  I assume you are booting into that instead to play the game.  I guess you can ignore my last comment about the operating system being off, but I would say it would be better to have a dedicated Windows machine.

Comment: will upgrading RAM and HDD to SSD show any difference or is external graphics card a best option?

Comment: RAM and HDD upgrades will do nothing

Comment: You fix it by getting a computer that meets the minimum system requirements, at least.  Beyond that, we can't help.

Comment: Unfortunately, as a gamer you need to expand your hardware to either a desktop with a decent graphics card, or an expensive laptop with non-integrated graphics.
I like the portability of a laptop as I'm a social gamer, but the desktop option is much cheaper. You'll probably find a basic machine that'll run Far Cry 4 off-the-shelf.

Comment: Whether it's Windows running on a Mac, or Windows running on a non-Mac, it makes absolutely no difference to the game. The problem here is the hardware, which simply does not meet the minimum requirements. The only fix is to buy a new PC. Unfortunately, [even the best Macbook Pro available does not meet the requirements for Far Cry 4](http://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-GTX-460-vs-AMD-R9-M370X/2167vsm30774).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the data from http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu_list.php, comparing your video card to the minimum requirements:

[image]

You'll notice your graphics does not meet the minimum requirements.